# Dynamic Programming: Finding the number of ways in which a order-dependant sum of numbers is less than or equal to a number

Tags: dynamic-programming

Given a number N, and a set S of numbers, find the number of ways in which a order-dependant sum of numbers of S is less than or equal to N. The numbers in S can occur more than once. For example, when N = 3 and S={1, 2}, the answer is 6. In this example, 1, 1+1, 2, 1+1+1, 1+2, 2+1 are less than or equal to 3.

Comment: find the number of ways in which a order-dependant sum of numbers of S is less than or equal to N

Comment: This is trivial to do just using recursion alone.

Comment: Ah, I've just worked out how to do it with dynamic programming.

Answer (score 0):

When `S = {1, 2}`, the answers for `N = 0, 1, 2...` are `0, 1, 3, 6, 11, 19, 32...`. Think about why these numbers might be the same as the Fibonacci sequence with 2 subtracted.

Answer (score 0):

When `S={n1, n2, …, nk}`, you have `f(N)=f(N-n1)+f(N-n2)+…+f(N-nk)`. So you just have to compute `f(i)` for `i < nk` and then you can easily compute `f(n)` with the formula `(f(n),f(n+1),…,f(n+nk))=(f(0),f(1),…,f(nk))*A^n` where `A` is the [companion matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Companion_matrix) of the sequence.